# How would I solve the following equation, which is similar to an algebraic Riccati equation or a nonlinear sylvester equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, control-theory

I have the following matrix equation that I would like to solve for $X$:

$0 = AX + XB + XCX + D$

In general, $X$ will be rectangular, with $(m\times n)$ dimensions. So if I write the equation out with indices, it is:

$0 = A_{mm}X_{mn} + X_{mn}B_{nn} + X_{mn}C_{nm}X_{mn} + D_{mn}$

I assume everything to be real, and $m,n$ are dimensions small enough that a diagonalization of an $m\times n$ matrix is computationally feasible.

I see that if $C=0$, then it is just a linear Sylvester equation, and if $A=B$ then it seems to be an Algebraic Riccati equation, but neither of these assertions can be made.

I appreciate any guidance towards a solution. Perhaps this is an equation with well known properties (I'm not a mathematician)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two remarks: 1. The equation is known to have many solutions. Are you interested in a particular one? (Tagging control-theory, maybe in the stabilizing solution?) 2. Are you familiar with the technique used in the symmetric case (Hamiltonian matrix, stable-unstable invariant subspace decomposition etc)? The nonsymmetric case is quite similar (see, for example, [here](https://books.google.se/books?id=Gi1jZAz3pncC&lpg=PR1&hl=sv&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Comment: [Relevant](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/volltexte/2008/1395/pdf/07461.IannazzoBruno.Paper.1395.pdf)

Comment: A.G: Thanks! While I expected this to have multiple solutions, I don't have a good way to determine which solution is best. I have arrived at this equation as a intermediate step in the solution of a much larger and "more nonlinear" equation (D is a complicated function of X) - such that I am going to solve the above equation to obtain a better guess for the next iteration of my larger equation. I appreciate your help, and it has given me a starting point.

Comment: bharb: Thank you for the link! Looks very relevant and helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a **nonsymmetric algebraic ricatti equation (NARE)**. You may google this term to find out the latest development.

Comment: [Here][1] you will find a paper with numerical methods to solve the NARE.


  [1]: http://drops.dagstuhl.de/volltexte/2008/1395/pdf/07461.IannazzoBruno.Paper.1395.pdf

Comment: I didn't notice that A.G. had provided a (very subtle) link in his/her comment too. The book chapter he/she linked to seems very useful.